# react-google-login uxMode = 'redirect ' not working properly

Tags: reactjs

am using [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login)

and I  used property uxMode = 'redirect', but sometimes onSuccess call back function is not working , is am  missing anything

```
     <GoogleLogin
              clientId={googleClientId}
              buttonText="Login"
              onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
              onFailure={this.onFailedResponseGoogle}
              accessType="online"
              uxMode='redirect'
            >
           <img src={googleIcon} id="googleIcon" />              
                <span> Sign in with Google</span>
      </GoogleLogin>
```

Comment: Facing the same issue, the response handler function doesn't seem to run as the component is unmounted on redirect.